# Azure Pipelines Build Validation For All Branch

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

As per reading from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

I have tested out the guide and it works for just 1 branch.

My question is that is there a way for me to do it for all of my branches?

Example branches name:

- feature/test-1
- feature/test-2
- feature/test-2-1
- rel/test-1
- master

I can PR feature/test-2-1 to feature/test-2

I can PR feature/test-2 to rel/test-1

But based on the example, I can only set to 1 branch and if I wanted the 2nd branch to have I need to set it manually.

Is there a way I can set that ALL PR must pass the validation before accepting it? No matter what is the branch name.

Answer (score 0):

In an single Git repository on Azure DevOps, you can only set protection policy for each branch individually.

However, on the project-level, you can set the [**Cross-repo branch policies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#cross-repo-branch-policies) that can be applied to all the matched branches in all repositories in current project.

**[UPDATE]**

Since the the Cross-repo branch policies will be applied to all the matched branches in all repositories in a project.

If you want the policies only can be applied to all the branches in a particular repository, you can only set the policies for each branch individually.

If you really need this feature, I recommend that you can report a feature request on [**Developer Community**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). That will make it possible for you to interact with the appropriate engineering team, and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Comment: But what if i only wanted to set for my project A only? While my project B and project C do not want this policies?

Comment: Hi@ZorevGnoz, what do you mean about `project A`, `project B` and `project C`? Are they different team projects in the same organization, or they are three different git repositories in the same team project?

Comment: 3 diff repo in the same team project

Comment: @ZorevGnoz, I have updated my answer with more details. Please check it.

Comment: Wow that's nonsense. Why would ADO (azure devops) have this feature only for _all_ repos not a single one..